# Optimize loading of 5400+ records

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, eloquent

I am building an application with the use of Slim and Twig as it's template engine, and am currently working on a page to display all user records.

The loading takes a lot of time, 11.25 seconds in fact, and my employer finds this an unreasonable loading time, and agree it should be possible to load it quicker.

I should mention I am using Eloquent as my ORM. to communicate with my Database. and for the pagination I am using [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net)

Here is a link to [Chrome dev-tool results](http://i.imgur.com/bUwp5Lw.jpg).

The Twig Template Page:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} | Administration</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/vendor/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/vendor/admin.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/main.css">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
         <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      {% include 'templates/partials/admin/navigation.php' %}
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
        {% include 'templates/partials/admin/menubar.php' %}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
        {% include 'templates/partials/messages.php' %} {% block content %}{% endblock %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  {% include 'templates/partials/admin/footer.php' %}
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/public/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
  });
</script>

</html>
```

User View page:

```html
{% extends 'templates/table.php' %} {% block title %}View users {% endblock %} {% block content %}

<h2> All Users </h2>
{% if users is empty%}
<p>No registered Users</p>
{% else %}

<table id="example" class="display" data-page-length='15' cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>Bedrijf</th>
    <th>Toegang Weigeren</th>
    <th>Naam:</th>
    <th>VCA</th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>registratie datum</th>
    <th>bestanden</th>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    {% for user in users %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{ user.IDSTUDENT }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ user.COMPANY_NAME }}
      </td>
      <td>
        Button here
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ user.STUDENT_NAME }} {{ user.STUDENT_FIRSTNAME }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ user.STUDENT_VCANUMMER }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ user.STUDENT_EMAIL }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ user.STUDENT_DATE }}
      </td>
      <td>
        Files go here
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
{% endif %} {% endblock %}
```

User route:

```php
<?php

$app->get('/users', function() use($app){

    $users = $app->user->where('STUDENT_LANG', 'nl')->get();
    $app->render('user/all.php', [
        'users' => $users
    ]);

})->name('user.all');
```

I have tried caching and compressing the files which brought it all down to the 11.25 seconds of load time, down from 16 seconds.

Advice would be most appreciated from anyone.

Comment: Why not render just *x* at a time? Scroll down with infinite scroll, get the next *x*?

Comment: Do you really want to show 5400 rows of data all in one go? Mybe you shoudl consider pagination and show just 20 or 30 at a time

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is showing 15 at any given time, though my boss demands that is be searchable and that seems rather (as far as i could see) IM possible when loading them X at a time. The demand is to be able to search all current and future records.

Comment: You just need to lookup `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

Try te following,

`$users = table_name::paginate(n);` . This will return you first *n* records. Identify the `id` of the last record. Send an `ajax request` on scroll with the `id` as the get parameter and query the database like,
`$users = table_name::where('id','>',identified_id)->paginate(n);`. This will get you the next *n* records

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lazy loading kind of pattern so at first time it will bring only limited number of records lets say 100 rows. when user scrolls down and reach at the end of page you can query for next 100 rows and show it on your page.